# Prevent modal from flashing during page loading

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, hide

I have scanned several other posts relating to this, but I cannot work out a working solution sadly.

Any help greatly appreciated.

I am trying to stop the modals flashing visibility briefly while the page is loading.  I have a 3D model that loads using OpenwebGL, so need a few seconds to load.  The modals flashing at the start looks untidy.

I'm not sure of the best approach to stop the modals from loading until the 3d model has finished loading.

This is the HTML code for the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Verge3D Web Interactive</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">

  <meta name="generator" content="Verge3D 3.0.1">

  <script src="ie_compat.js"></script>
  <script src="webxr-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script>var polyfill = new WebXRPolyfill();</script>
  <script src="ammo.js"></script>

  <script src="v3d.js"></script>
  <script src="City_20_01c.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="City_20_01c.css">
  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="fullscreen_button" class="fullscreen-button fullscreen-open" title="Toggle fullscreen mode"></div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal01" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="display:none">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Add any html and CSS Element here.  Images , Video, Text, etc</p>
    </br>
  <img src="http://avologypro.com/wp/expleo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Screenshot-2020-02-09-13.25.13.png"  width="325px" height="170px"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example 02</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal02" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Automotive 02</p>
    <p>Add any html and CSS Element here.  Images , Video, Text, etc</p>
    </br>
          <img src="http://avologypro.com/wp/expleo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Screenshot-2020-02-09-13.25.13.png"  width="325px" height="170px"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code snippet is not working it gives an error  ` "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: WebXRPolyfill is not defined"`

Comment: Hi Reymon.  This is because I have not linked the WebOpenGL file and is not related to the flash problem above.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Me again.

Ok appreciate a lot of questions on the forum regarding this topic, but didn't find an easy fit.

I eventually figured out a solution using the following from various ideas combined.

So for anyone else trying to fix this issue in the future try the following:

Put the modal div's in a new div. Make the parent div invisible using a style comment in the header.  Add this to the opening body comment onload="showdiv();", 
 Then add a function showdiv script at the bottom of your body.

Here is the same HTML above with the new adjustments:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Verge3D Web Interactive</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

 
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn.soft8soft.com/images/player_socials.jpg">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">

  <meta name="generator" content="Verge3D 3.0.1">

  <!-- favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="media/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="media/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="media/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="media/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="media/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <script src="ie_compat.js"></script>
  <script src="webxr-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script>var polyfill = new WebXRPolyfill();</script>
  <script src="ammo.js"></script>
  

  
  <script src="v3d.js"></script>
  <script src="City_20_01c.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="City_20_01c.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
        #modaloff {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body onload="showdiv();">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="fullscreen_button" class="fullscreen-button fullscreen-open" title="Toggle fullscreen mode"></div>
  </div>

<div id="modaloff">
 <div class="container" id="modaloff01" >
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal01" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Add any html and CSS Element here.  Images , Video, Text, etc</p>
    </br>
  <img src="http://avologypro.com/wp/expleo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Screenshot-2020-02-09-13.25.13.png"  width="325px" height="170px"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example 02</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal02" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header 02</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Automotive 02</p>
    <p>Add any html and CSS Element here.  Images , Video, Text, etc</p>
    </br>
          <img src="http://avologypro.com/wp/expleo/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Screenshot-2020-02-09-13.25.13.png"  width="325px" height="170px"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function showdiv() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("modaloff").style.visibility = "visible";
        }, 5000);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```